# There are vs are there

Tags: grammar, inversion

> Nowhere in the United States but in New Jersey ______ so many people per square mile.

- a) there
- b) there are
- c) there is
- d) are there

The correct one is **d**.

When I use *are there*?
Why is *there are* not correct, is it not about existence?

Can anyone here explain this to  me?

Comment: For the purpose of emphasis, **nowhere** sometime comes at the beginning of the sentence. And the verb comes before the subject. For example - **Nowhere had I less expected to see her than in my house.** In your sentence *Nowhere in the United States but in New Jersey* is an adverbial, and *there* is the subject, *are* is the verb. So the correct sentence is **Nowhere in the United States but in New Jersey are there so many people per square mile.** With **there are** in the blanks, there special stress will be missing, but not incorrect, in my opinion.

Answer (score 8):

**From Practical English Usage by Michael Swan -**

[image]

[image]

We can use **nowhere** at the beginning of the sentence for the purpose of emphasis, and then **auxiliary verb** will precede the **subject**.

**Example -**

> **Nowhere** *had* *I* less expected to see her than in my house.

In your example sentence, **Nowhere in the United States but in New Jersey** is a negative adverbial. **There** is the subject and **are** is the verb. So if it follows the same pattern it will be something like that -

> **Nowhere in the United States but in New Jersey** *are there* so many people per square mile.

[I don't know if we use **there are** in the blank, it would be incorrect, but surely the stress factor would be missing. And it's recommended to use the inversion there. So it's better to stick to that.]

Comment: Thanks for this reminder. I had completely forgotten this. +1 for that! :)

Answer (score 0):

"Nowhere in the United States but in New Jersey" is the subject of *are*.

*There* is a pronoun that takes the place of an explicit noun/noun phrase.  Since you explicitly state the subject, the pronoun is not needed and sounds awkward if you put it in there.

It's like saying:

> John he went to the park.

Comment: I'd have thought the syntactic "subject" in OP's context is *so many people per square mile* - as seems more obvious if you reorder and simplify to *So/that many people [per square mile] **are** in NJ [but nowhere else]*.

Comment: @Man_From_India: It seems to me that with, say, *Nowhere in the United States **is** so nice* (or even just *Nowhere **is** nicer*), the word ***nowhere*** (whether further qualified or not) is the syntactic "subject". And it's singular, which is why the verb form becomes ***is*** there. In OP's context, as you originally commented, the correct verb form is ***are*** (imho because the subject is plural ***people***, which I think makes this answer incorrect).

Comment: @FumbleFingers *There is/are so many people per mile* explains which is the correct verb. I agree with you.

Answer (score -1):

A much simpler answer is that "there are" implies a statement, while "are there" is a question.  For example:

> There are many people.

versus

> Are there many people?

Comment: True, but here **are there** is used not in a question, but in a statement :-)

Comment: /\ That's it. :D